# Why am I getting this error: Ambiguous reference to member 'fetch(with:parse:completion:)'

Tags: ios, swift

I am using **Xcode 8.3.3**. I am getting a **Swift** Compiler Error **"Ambiguous reference to member"**. I have gone over the code and can't seem to figure it out.

```
protocol APIClient {
var session: URLSession { get }
func fetch<T: JSONDecodable>(with request: URLRequest, parse: @escaping (JSON) -> T?, completion: @escaping (Result<T, APIError>) -> Void)

    func fetch<T: JSONDecodable>(with request: URLRequest, parse: @escaping (JSON) -> [T], completion: @escaping (Result<[T], APIError>) -> Void)
}
fetch(with: request, parse: { json -> [YelpBusiness] in
            guard let businesses = json["businesses"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return [] }
            return businesses.flatMap { YelpBusiness(json: $0) }
}, completion: completion)
```

https://github.com/jripke74/RestaurantReviews.git

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. You have created a `protocol` which confirms the class `YelpClient`. What's wrong?

```
fetch(with: request, parse: { json -> [YelpBusiness] in
            guard let businesses = json["businesses"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return [] }
            return businesses.flatMap { YelpBusiness(json: $0) }
}, completion: completion)
```

Using above code you are directly calling the `protocol` without any `delegate`. The problem is you need to inherit the `protocol` in the `YelpClient` class like below.

```
func fetch<T>(with request: URLRequest, parse: @escaping (APIClient.JSON) -> T?, completion: @escaping (Result<T, APIError>) -> Void) where T : JSONDecodable {
    //Code
}

func fetch<T>(with request: URLRequest, parse: @escaping (APIClient.JSON) -> [T], completion: @escaping (Result<[T], APIError>) -> Void) where T : JSONDecodable {
    //Code
}
```

For more details refer to apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

> Updated:

Check the below screenshot for better idea

[image]

Comment: I believe the code is correct but if you run the code (I include GitHub link). You get a Ambiguous reference to member 'fetch(with:parse:completion:)' error.

Comment: @JeffA.Ripke Code is correct, but you have implemented the `protocol` in a wrong way. You are mixing `protocol` and `closure`. The way you are calling `protocol` is not correct. You need to inherit it in the class rather than calling directly.

Comment: @JeffA.Ripke In shorter way, I can say that `protocol` is implemented not called directly.

Comment: Sorry, I just included protocol and function call in this post. I did inherit the code in YelpClient. I am just confused....